# MySQL data type confusion. In the mannual it says "but should be no greater than M−2."

Tags: mysql

In MySQL Mannual [it says](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-types.html)

> The maximum possible value is 30, but should be no greater than M−2.

However, I tried the following code and it still worked:

```
create table test (
a float(2,1),
);

insert into test(a) values (1.2);

select * from test;
```

In this case, the decimal precision is `1` which is clearly greater than `M-2=2-2=0`.

My confusion is how to interpret the mannual.

Comment: It doesn't say that MySQL checks that you meet the requirement. Apparently it doesn't.

Comment: @Barmar On the actual [man page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html) for `FLOAT`, this requirement does not appear.

Comment: And it's a should - not a must not. In fact, the float is created the same for large ranges of values  "A precision from 0 to 23 results in a 4-byte single-precision FLOAT column. A precision from 24 to 53 results in an 8-byte double-precision DOUBLE column."

Comment: @Jan Thanks for your answer! However would you please explain why it should be avoided?

Comment: I only have guesswork on that part - like possible strange behaviour you get when 5 + 5 != 10 because your float(30,30) could not hold the data.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation that `MySQL` has provided

> MySQL permits a nonstandard syntax: FLOAT(M,D) or REAL(M,D) or DOUBLE
>   PRECISION(M,D). Here, (M,D) means than values can be stored with up to
>   M digits in total, of which D digits may be after the decimal point.
>   For example, a column defined as FLOAT(7,4) will look like -999.9999
>   when displayed. MySQL performs rounding when storing values, so if you
>   insert 999.00009 into a FLOAT(7,4) column, the approximate result is
>   999.0001.

This means in your case `float(2,1)` `MSQL` allows maximum 2 digits before decimal and 1 digit after decimal that means `1.2` will be allow.

If you insert `1.26` then `MySQL` will insert `1.3` in table It will round off the value.
Plus `MySQl` state this in other documentation,

> "DECIMAL"=>my %DataType = 'if ($M < $D) {return $D + 2;} elsif ($D > 0) {return $M +
>   2;} else {return $M + 1;}';

Hope this clarify you. Please refer [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html).